# Enable or disable the biometric login in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, biometrics

I'm developing an iPhone application in swift. In my app, its provide users to login by using the faceID or touchID. And it is working fine. Also in my app settings page, there is a switch button to enable or disable biometric login. That is if the switch button is enable means users can login to the app using touchID or faceID, if it is disable means users can't login using touchID or faceID. Can I able to enable and disable this feature? And how can I do that. Please help me.

Comment: Check the switch value from `UserDefaults` and if it is off, don't use Biometric login?

Answer (score 3):

IF you have implemented TouchID or FaceID in your project user login using biometric login and do off TouchID from setting screen in your app, then you need to store one flag in `NSUserDefaults` and check next time when user try to login in your app, if you found a flag from `NSUserDefaults` then you need to show alert message "Touch ID disable now for this app" like that, and also you need to give alternative option to log in for this app, But there is no way to disable TouchID or FaceID apple not allowed to disable this functionality. So you need to handle this scenario using own login.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, when I started looking at implementing biometrics I had assumed you have to register the app somehow and then check this value when the app is launched. I didn't realise it was as simple as setting a flag!